# VSCode - multiline selection - aligning with TAB

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quite often I have to change CSV files into PHP arrays and I almost got a quick way of doing it but there's last bit I can't figure out.

I get from this csv

```
label_a         label_b
test_a          test_b
test1111_a      test1111_b
test2222222_a   test2222222_b
```

to this:

```
"test_a" => "test_b",
"test1111_a" => "test1_b",
"test2222222_a" => "test2_b"
```

But I have a problem aligning the `=>`, I would like to align them like this:

```
"test_a"        => "test_b",
"test1111_a"    => "test1_b",
"test2222222_a" => "test2_b"
```

I keep my cursor here:

```
"test_a" |=> "test_b",
"test1111_a" |=> "test1_b",
"test2222222_a" |=> "test2_b"
```

but pressing tab, it obviously moves each line one tab (2 spaces in my case). Is there anyway to do it with VSCode? (maybe it's just wishful thinking)

Comment: There are a lot of `align` extensions - in this case you would specify `=>` as the characters to align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add spaces so all cursors are beyond the point you want the `==>` to be
- press home to get all cursors to position 1
- move cursors to wanted position (ArrowRight)
- press `Ctrl+Delete` it will delete all spaces between cursors and `=`

Comment: ooooo! the `Ctrl+Delete` is a neat trick I had no idea about! I wish that moving cursors to wanted position were a bit easier and with using TAB as well but this is still big improvement. Thanks!

Comment: @Moseleyi At the moment all Multi Cursors are handling the keystrokes independent, if you want a different behavior you have to write an extension and a few keybindings, you can use `editorHasMultipleSelections` in the when clause, it all depends if you need it regularly

Comment: Multiple times every day. Mostly for aligning select statements in SQL or PHP arrays but what you suggested is already heaps better than what I had (nothing).

Comment: @Moseleyi you can search the market place for `align`, there are numerous extensions that do some sort of alignment